# mysql insert select conundrum

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm trying to insert select but I'm confused as to how to populate just 1 item into the destination table from the select, and populate the rest with static values.

This is all in a stored procedure... so... here's what i'm trying to do...

```
table:animals
id   |type| name
1    |cat  | mittens
2    |cat  | fluffy
3    |dog  | rex

table people_with_pets
persons_name | pets_name
Arnold       | rex
```

defined variable owner = "Joe";

so... joe loves cats and I want to insert all the names of the from the `animals` table into the `people_with_pets` table, along with "joe".

so, I'd like to `select name from animals where type like 'cats';`

and insert the resulting values along with "joe" into (in this case 2) new rows in `people_with_pets`.

I'm not sure if insert select gets me this, it seems like it might, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT INTO people_with_pets (persons_name, pets_name) SELECT 'Joe', name FROM animals WHERE type = 'cat';

Answer (score 4):

INSERT INTO people_with_pets SELECT 'Joe', name FROM animals WHERE type = 'cat';

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to do is to associate all cat types to Joe and insert into the table `people_with_pets`, to show the `persons_name` Joe along with other cat names, by using a single insert select statement.

So there is what I did:

```
INSERT INTO people_with_pets
(SELECT 'Joe', name FROM animals WHERE type like 'cat');
```

The result should show you this:

```
mysql> select * from people_with_pets;

+--------------+-----------+
| persons_name | pets_name |
+--------------+-----------+
| Arnold       | rex       |
| Joe          | mittens   |
| Joe          | fluffy    |
+--------------+-----------+
```

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Sorry please note that type = 'cat' is more precise than type like 'cat'. As if you have an animal type catfish, things might get confusing. Although for current situation both will return the same result.